# android video player with play and pause

Tags: android, video, media-player

I am developing an application , in which the items are to be display in a list, and while selecting the particular item, its video should be play. please suggest me how to do this. I need video player with play and pause buttons. kindly post some codes. I am beginner.

thanks a lot to spend your time here.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will simply redirect you to native video player, which by default has the ability to pause and play.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(//provide working url here)));
```